# How to pass special characters to geoprocessing tool?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, arcgis-workflow-manager

I have a geoprocessing service to create various tasks. So the paarmeters for JTXSteps.ExecuteGPTool are here
 /addjobcomment `/url:"https://xyz/arcgis/rest/services/F2F_Workflow/Task/GPServer/CreateTask/submitJob?job_type_name=drafting&job_name=[JOB:NAME]&description=&owned_by=[JOB:OWNED_BY]&assigned_to=[JOBEX:WSP_TASK.DRAFTING_ROLE]&project_job_id=[JOB:PARENT_JOB]&initiator_job_id=[JOBEX:INITIATOR_JOB_ID]....&f=pjson"`

I have a requirement now to pass this string !@#$%^&*()_+/;:"',.?][}{| as job name essentially to capture all possible special characters in other systems for project names. I have noticed '#' breaks the sequence of parameters and with '&' rest of the string for the Job_name gets ignored. The call to submit GP jobs are expected through workflows and parameters are being read from SQL server tables for subsequent tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Use url encoding. In python 2 that is in the urllib package. Might be able to use parse

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse

Comment: I tried using urllib but the parameters here are NAME value of JOB table which is the standard job table (sde.JTX_JOBS).

Comment: I don't get what the problem is, urlencode should be able to encode any object, and parse should be able to un-encode it.